# Combine Vehicle Plate Without Repetition

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have a vehicle registration plate model that uses $3$ letters and $5$ numbers. There cannot be no repetitions in the plate.

Suppose the second letter is Z and the last number is $0$. How many combinations can I have?

- For letters: (assuming $26$ letters) I have $\underbrace{25}_{26 - 1} \times \underbrace{1}_{\text{Z}} \times \underbrace{24}_{26 - 1 - 1}$.

For numbers, same thought: $9 \times 8 \times 7 \times 6 \times 1$.

The answer would be the multiplication of these results. Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the correct way. The result is just the product of the different possibilities for each slot.